# Como recuperar um projeto usando Angular 2 que foi danificado com "npm update"

Tags: angular, npm, workspace

Retomei meus estudos com Angular 2, e estou tentando reconstruir o [projeto deste link](https://github.com/becompany/angular2-rss-reader-tutorial) passo a passo, porém ao executar a atualização dos pacotes com `npm update` não consigo mais testar o projeto com `ng serve`, recebendo diversas mensagens de ausência de pacotes ou outros erros.

por Exemplo:

```
ERROR in ./~/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common/http' in 'C:\Users\Admin\workspace\islan\angular2-rss-reader2\node_modules\@angular\material\esm5'
 @ ./~/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js 9:0-50
 @ ./~/@angular/material/esm5/material.es5.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200/ ./src/main.ts
```

Considerando uma instalação padrão feita do Angular 2 na data de `10/07/2019`, e um projeto criado com `ng new`, quais são as versões dos pacotes abaixo mais indicadas para que o projeto seja compilado com sucesso?

```
"dependencies": {
   "@angular/common": "",
   "@angular/compiler": "",
   "@angular/core": "",
   "@angular/forms": "",
   "@angular/http": "",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "",
   "@angular/router": "",
   "@angular/material": "",
   "@angular/cdk": "",
   "@angular/animations": "",
   "core-js": "",
   "rxjs": "",
   "ts-helpers": "",
   "zone.js": ""
},
"devDependencies": {
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "",
   "@types/jasmine": "",
   "@types/node": "",
   "angular-cli": "",
   "codelyzer": "",
   "jasmine-core": "",
   "jasmine-spec-reporter": "",
   "karma": "",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "",
   "karma-cli": "",
   "karma-jasmine": "",
   "karma-remap-istanbul": "",
   "protractor": "",
   "ts-node": "",
   "tslint": "",
   "typescript": ""
}
```

Grato

Answer (score 1):

Rapaz... Muita coisa mudou desde a versão 2 até a versão 8 (atualmente), certos pacotes mudaram de nome ou foram substituídos.

No seu caso, eu criaria um projeto novo, e iria fazendo parte por parte (lazy loading, Observable, ...)

Aqui tem um site que diz o que precisa atualizar de uma versão para outra:

[Update Angular Cli](https://update.angular.io/)

Existe vários artigos no site Medium que te ajudam com isso:

[Lazy Loading Angular 7](https://medium.com/@thiago.reis/how-to-implement-lazy-loading-in-angular-c8dcbf165561)

[Lazy Loading Angular 8](https://medium.com/@nishu0505/lazy-loading-in-angular-8-10fc59fdfb04)

E tem as videos aulas da Loiane, que ensinam a fazer um CRUD e todo o mais (os últimos são os mais atualizados):
[Loiane Groner - Curso de Angular](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGxZ4Rq3BOBoSRcKWEdQACbUCNWLczg2G)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu confesso que fico muito perdido quando uso Angular, são muitas versões totalmente incompatíveis, eu uso NativeScript e sempre recebo mensagens dizendo que devo migrar para a versão 6, não posso usar agora nem a 7 nem a 8 e não é produtivo ficar mudando de versão continuamente,  Estou tentando exatamente fazer isso, criei o projeto novo, e fui copiando os fontes de app, mas nunca dá certo, e no final acaba virando uma sala de versões.

Comment: Outro fato interessante, ao criar um projeto novo com `ng new` é usado pacotes na versão ^2.*.*, já no nativescript está usando pacotes da versão `^8.*.*`.

Comment: o ng new é referente a versão do angular - cli instalada

Comment: Bem, uso no nativescript e tudo está ok, e nem quero mudar nada pois confesso que temo pela saúde do projeto. vou atuar globalmente para ver oque acontece.

Comment: Infelizmente não posso  atualizar para a ultima versão, ele exige o node 10 e vou ter problemas com outros projetos, e manter agora diversas instalações não será viável.

Comment: Olha, tenho um colega de equipe que usa duas versões do Angular (7 e 8 no caso). EU não sei como ele fez isso, mas acredito que isso te ajudaria neste problema, e ir migrando os outros projetos para a versão mais atual, e deixar os outros rodando na produção na versão antiga.

Comment: O interessante é ir se atualizando. A Loiane (youtuber) tem videos mostrando como passar de uma versão para a outra. Talvez isso te ajude na migração futura.